# Issue with Deeplink to Sidepanel Redirect in Microsoft Teams In-Meeting App

Tags: teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

We were developing the Microsoft team's in-meeting app using the @microsoft/teams-js client-side library. In that, we have the use case to send the target notification to specific participants at the meeting. Upon completion of the participant's activity within the target notification, we have to direct the participant from the targeted notification to the meeting side panel by clicking the button on the target notification.

Code which I'm using to Open deeplink

`const deepLink ="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/566c8d1d-b089-465f-8fdf-8fd82e771155/sidepanel?webUrl=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a53000%2findex.html%23%2finvoiceConfirm%3fid%3dE20231215111611%26sessionId%3dq2pj49bq33yhv9mb6htdxpbtwc4k%26screen%3dpreview%26customer%3dMuthukumar&label=Test&context=%7b%22chatId%22%3a%2219%3ameeting_M2NiMWVlZjctYmFkMC00Y2U5LWFkNTItODA5NTNiYTRjMTRl%40thread.v2%22%2c%22contextType%22%3a%22chat%22%7d";`
`app.openLink(deepLink);`

Getting Following error:

`either targetOrigin or target is invalid`

Comment: Error Occurs when we are attempting to redirect to the side panel from the targeted notification popup. I've tested pasting the link in the chat, and that is working.

Comment: Issue has been fixed by using following format for generating deeplink:           `const appId = configData.TEAMS_APP_ID;
            const entityId = "sidepanel";
            const webUrl = "https://localhost:53000/index.html#/sidepanel/task123";
            const encodedWebUrl = encodeURIComponent(webUrl);
            const encodedContext = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ "chatId": `${props.chatId}`, "contextType": "chat" }));
            const deepLink = `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${appId}/${entityId}?weburl=${encodedWebUrl}&context=${encodedContext}&openInMeeting=true;`